# Did Google change the functionality of postcode_localities in the geocode API

Tags: google-geocoding-api

We are using the geocoding API to supply suggestions for cities when the user enters a US zip code.  We use the following:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key={our_key}&address=17756](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=%7Bour_key%7D&address=17756)

Until recently, this has returned with two values in the postcode_localities array; Muncy and Pennsdale, which are the two city (locality) names valid for this US zip code.

However, within the last few days, this same call returns an array of 11 values, none of which are the cities (localities) within this zip code.  The 11 values are all townships within the zip code which are administrative_area_level_3 types.

I have done some Googling to find how others determine the cities associated with a zip code and this method is what all the answers suggest.

Is anyone aware of a change in Google's interpretation of what they are putting in the postcode_localities array?

Is there something I can provide in the request to force the postcode_localities array to contain localities instead of administrative_area_level_3 values?

Update 2/21: I received a response from Google support.  It seems that they recognize this as a problem but, according to them, it's too soon to know when it will be fixed.